# unexpected results on simple string reverse algorithm

Tags: c, string, algorithm, reverse

I'm relatively new to C. I wanted to lern the language a bit by solving [coderbyte challenges](https://coderbyte.com/challenges/).

But I'm stucked at the first. It is supposed to be a simple String reverse algorithm.

When I input things like "asdf" or "1234567" the output is correct ("fdsa", "7654321"). But when I type "12345678" or "thisiscool" I get "87654321▒@"/"loocsisiht@" as a result. I don't know where the @ are comming from.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void FirstReverse(char str[]) {

  int len = strlen(str);
  char nstr[len];
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      nstr[i] = *(str+len-1-i);
  }

  printf("%s\n", nstr);

}
int main(void) {

  char str[100];

  FirstReverse(gets(str));
  return 0;

}
```

Can someone please tell me where I can find the error?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `strlen` returns the length *without* the nul termination, so `nstr` is too small. You also don't assign the nul termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers have mentioned, you're missing a terminator.
It should also be noted that it's bad practice to allocate strings the way you did. An array should always have a fixed size if you create it that way.

You should instead do:

```
char * nstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len+1));
```

Thereby allocating the size of each character (1 byte) times the lenght.
Note the +1 because you need room for the string terminator.

When you call printf(, string); , it's gonna start from the first letter and print everything up to the terminator. Since you have no terminator here, it prints random characters, such as @.

What you're gonna wanna do to fix that, is adding:

```
nstr[i] = '\0';
```

after your loop.

Also remember to free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are zero-terminated. A string "cat", for example, has 4 characters, and is represented as ('c','a','t',(char)0).  You forgot about the final 0.

Note that `strlen` returns the string length without the final `0`, so a string `foo` contains `strlen(foo)+1` characters.  Remember this when you allocate strings.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate a char for the terminating '\0' in nstr[].

So, better use: `char nstr[len + 1];` and set `nstr[len] = 0;`

Furthermore: `gets()` is evil: from the glibc manual page:

Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to  break  computer  security.   Use  fgets() instead.